# Why both ioremap() and kmap() are needed?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

In case of memory mapped IO: both memory mapped IO and RAM are in same CPU physical address space.
When we map any higmem memory we use `kmap()` and when we need to map memory mapped IO we use `ioremap()`.
So my question is why we need to separate functions to get kernel virtual address, since both (memory mapped IO and RAM)  are in the same physical address space?
Why can't we have single function, as both are creating virtual address for some CPU physical address.

Comment: Both may be in the same physical address space, but do not require the same memory attributes.  The virtual memory mapped for I/O, for instance, is always marked as *non-cacheable*, *non-swapable*, and *non-executable*  memory.

Comment: @sawdust..Thanks for your answer , got some clarification .